# How can I remove one element in a json string in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, string, format

I have this payload:

```
payload = {
    "cluster": "analytics",
    "id_pipeline": "123456789",
    "schema_compatibility": "backward",
    "branch": "production"
}
```

And I need to remove the element "id_pipeline" and its value ("123456789").

Any suggestions? I made this code but this errors appears: "'str' object does not support item deletion"

```
for element in payload_data:
    if 'id_pipeline' in element:
        del element['id_pipeline']
```

The desirable output payload is something like this:

```
payload = {
    "cluster": "analytics",
    "schema_compatibility": "backward",
    "branch": "production"
}
```

Obs: I need to keep json format.

Comment: `del payload['id_pipeline']`

Comment: Do you mean that you have a `dict` called `payload` and you want to remove an element? Did you mean `del payload["id_pipeline"]`?

Comment: Even if it is a JSON string and not a dictionary, the easiest way is probably to parse it as a dictionary with `json.loads`, delete the key and write the resulting dictionary back to the JSON file.

Comment: _"I have tried using pop method"_: Don't just describe what you tried. _Show_ it: Add your code as a [mre] in a [formatted code-block](/help/formatting), and tell us why it didn't meet your requirements. Please take the [tour] and read [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: @Jijo Alexander, thanks, this worked fine. I used a json.dumps(payload) to return to a valid json. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `del` function to remove the selected key from the existing dictionary. Also adding a good read for better understanding - https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-remove-a-key-from-dictionary/

```
payload = {
    "cluster": "analytics",
    "id_pipeline": "123456789",
    "schema_compatibility": "backward",
    "branch": "production"
}    

del payload['id_pipeline']

print(payload)
```

#OUT PUT

> {
> "cluster": "analytics",
> "schema_compatibility": "backward",
> "branch": "production" }

[image]

Comment: Such questions have usually already been asked and answered. Since the Stack Overflow community prefers that answers to the same question be consolidated under the same post, the recommended action here is to look for and flag/vote as a duplicate instead of adding an answer to the new question.